# Is F# Type Provider SQL loading all the Database in VS?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using FSharp.Data.Sql to access via the Type Provider to a MSSQL database.
No problem with using it, however, I have the feeling that VS is loading all the database when I am typing code which make the visual studio process very heavy (2GB of RAM used compared to a few MB when I am not using it) and very slow.

I thought that

```
let [<Literal>] connectionString = """Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XX;"""

type sql = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString = connectionString, DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER, IndividualsAmount = 1000, UseOptionTypes = true >

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
```

Have you ever met the same issue? I did not find much in the official doc.

Thanks !

Comment: The type provider won't load the data but it needs the schema to generate the types and provide intellisense

Comment: Hi It is what I understood, the problem is that VS becomes very slow and very heavy... not sure if others had the same feeling. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the database. If you try to use that in a SAP or AX database with thousands of tables I'd expect problems. How many tables and *columns* are there? What does `select count(*) from sys.columns` return?

Comment: 881. Doesn't seem too excessive, I guess the answer is the correct reason. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to the following issues:

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5929

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5931

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5933

Type Providers (both the SDK and the extensibility point in the compiler) were not implemented in a way that works particularly well for a long-running process such as the F# compiler service. It's ironic since they're useful mostly in editing scenarios, but it is what it is. When these are addressed you can expect most memory usage woes to go away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no issue in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 3.0.
thanks